# Measuring and saving total time of a task for long time by an STM32 board

Tags: microcontroller

I have a [STM32F3](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0365-stm32f302xbcde-and-stm32f302x68-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) series Nucleo board and I use a display to show some parameters from this uC.

I want to display the total elapsed time of a task and display it cumulatively even after the board power is turned off. For example:

The uC is turned ON and monitoring the value of X. Now the value X is above a threshold and the uC should start recording elapsed time. At some point if it detects the value X is below threshold it should stop recording the time. And even after its power OFF and ON again it should start measuring elapsed time on the top off the previous value.

So the latest elapsed time data should be saved somewhere. This can be several years and what approach can be used in this case?

(Similar to car indicator showing how many km they are driven from the beginning)

Comment: Sounds like you might want to add an RTC to your design and some non-volatile memory (EEPROM), into which you will periodically save the time.

Comment: The board has both it seems. But Im mostly looking for how to start and the approach.

Comment: As I said - the approach is to periodically save the time in non-volatile memory. Why periodically? Because the system might get turned off at any point of time not giving it a chance to record the final time. But it also should not be too often, as the storage is wearing out.

Comment: How about how to calculate and monitor the elapsed time when a variable is beyond a threshold? Using timers? Then the recording/saving periodically is needed as you say.

Comment: This is a basic program logic I am sure you can figure out yourself. Just a bunch of conditional statements.

Comment: I think I need a function that would return datetime of now. And for that I need to use RTC. And then google for if theres such function. I know that in C# .NET there is. But in this case never tried.

Comment: Look up RTC code examples for your board, pretty sure you can find some that are coming with the CubeMX or whatever software package you are using to program your board. Or google it [as I did](https://controllerstech.com/internal-rtc-in-stm32/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flash memory.  It's non-volatile, which is your main criterion, but isn't quite as easy to use as, say, EEPROM.

I suggest you read ST's Application Note 4894: "EEPROM emulation techniques and software for STM32 microcontrollers", ([link](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4894-eeprom-emulation-techniques-and-software-for-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf)) which gives full information for this kind of use.

Other possibilities:

- Add some other kind of EEPROM in hardware, (one of the very many is 24LC32, interfaced over i2c)
- Send syslog packets to some kind of log server (eg syslog over UDP over ethernet) if your installation has those resources
- Whether you need a real-time clock depends on what your application actually wants.  Graphs of your resource over time might be very useful.

Comment: How about how to calculate and monitor the elapsed time when a variable is beyond a threshold?

Comment: How you do the time of variable-exceeds-threshold depends entirely on your accuracy required.  Why not edit your question with a bit more information.

Comment: So do I need a function which gives the date time when X is beyond threshold and periodically measures elapsed time and add it to eeprom. But do you know what function would return datetime?

Comment: Just to repeat: How you do the time of variable-exceeds-threshold depends entirely on your accuracy required.  What accuracy do you require?

Comment: Accuracy of up to 1 hour error is ok in a year.

Comment: ... and how fast is X changing?

Comment: X is changing min every 30 minutes max 7 days.